# Best way to implement a large 2D Lookup Table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lookup-tables

I am developing a Rails app and one of my actions compares two of the same kind of objects and returns a decimal value between 0 and 1. There are roughly 800 objects that need to be compared, thus there are roughly 800*800 possible decimal values that can be returned. Each action call requires about 300 or so comparisons, which are made via an API.

Because of the number of API calls that are needed, I have decided that the best approach is to make a lookup table with all 800*800 API comparison values stored locally, to avoid having to rely on the API, which has call limits and a significant overhead per call.

Basically I have decided that a lookup table best suits this task (although I am open for suggestions on this too).

My question is this: what is the best way to implement a 2 dimensional lookup table with ~800 "rows" and ~800 "columns" in rails? For example, if I wanted to compare objects 754 and 348, Would it be best to create models for the rows and columns and access the decimal comparison like:

```
object1.754.object2.348 # => 0.8738
```

Or should I store all of the values in a CSV or something like this? If this is the better approach, how should I even approach setting this up? I am relatively new to the rails world so apologies if an obvious answer is dangling in front of me!

Bear in mind that the entire point of this approach was to avoid the overheads from API calls and thus avoid large waiting times for the end user, so I am looking for the most time-efficient way to approach this task!

Comment: Mongodb, Postgres or any possible DB?

Comment: `640_000` doesn't really sound like much. If these are just 8 bytes per entry, you won't use up too much memory on plain arrays. NB: that only works fine if values are sequential integers, like 1-800.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a hash of hashes, so you retrieve the values with:

```
my_hash[754][348]
=> 0.8738
```

If you might not have already loaded the value for a particular combination then you'd want to be careful to use:

```
my_hash[754].try(:[],348)
```

There could be some subtleties in the implimentation to do with loading the hash that make it beneficial to use the hashie gem.

https://rubygems.org/gems/hashie/versions/3.4.2

If you wanted to persist the values then it can be written into a database using serialize, and you can also extend the method to provide expiry dates on the values as well if you wished.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go. Could you elaborate a but more on "serialize"?

Comment: It's a way of storing a complete object, such as a hash, or an array, or a Book, or a Person, as a single value in a database table. You could save the entire hash as a single attribute. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem comparing the contents of a large collection of ebooks, I stored the allready compared results in a matrix that I serialise with Marshal, the lookup key is a 2 dimensional array of the MD5 value of the filepath.
Here I add the Matric class I created for this task.

```
require 'digest/md5' 

class Matrix
  attr_accessor :path, :store

  def initialize path
    @path = path
    @store = File.open(@path,'rb') { |f| Marshal.load(f.read) } rescue Hash.new(nil)
  end

  def save
    File.open(@path,'wb') { |f| f.write(Marshal.dump(@store)) }
    self
  end

  def add file1, file2, value
    @store[[Digest::MD5.hexdigest(file1), Digest::MD5.hexdigest(file2)]] = value
  end

  def has? file1, file2
    !@store[[Digest::MD5.hexdigest(file1), Digest::MD5.hexdigest(file2)]].nil?
  end

  def value file1, file2
    @store[[Digest::MD5.hexdigest(file1), Digest::MD5.hexdigest(file2)]]
  end

  def each &blk
    @store.each &blk
  end

end
```